# Bar chart using achartengine with each category as separately

Tags: android, graph, charts, bar-chart, achartengine

See the barchart in image friends.

[image]

this is my problem. It shows like all categories in first place itself. I want each category as separately. Which means `Salary` in first place, `Pocket Money` in second place, `Travel` in third place and `Entertainment` in fourth place.

My code is as follows.

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getBarDemoRenderer();
        setChartSettings(renderer);
        layout.removeAllViews();
        layout.addView(ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, getBarDemoDataset(),
                renderer, Type.DEFAULT));
```

and

```
    public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarDemoRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();     
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);      
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});    
    SimpleSeriesRenderer r;

    for (int i = 0; i < income_list.size(); i++) {
        r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color.get(i));
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        r.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    }
    return renderer;
}

private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
    renderer.setXTitle("Category");
    renderer.setYTitle("Amount");
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(4.5);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(10000);
}

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDemoDataset() {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    for (int i = 0; i < income_list.size(); i++) {
        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(cat.get(i));
        series.add(income_list.get(i));
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

Please help me friends. I am trying this still last 6 hours friends. Still I didn't get any idea. using `achartengine` is more helpful.

Thainks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating `CategorySeries`, create `XYSeries` and add your items this way:

```
series.add(i + 1, income_list.get(i));
```

Then, you can just do `dataset.addSeries(series);` as it is already an `XYSeries`, you won't have to call `toXYSeries()`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.